# onActionReceivedMethod in flutter not opening navigating

Tags: flutter, push-notification

I am using `awesome_notification` for my FCM push message and everything is working perfectly but I am having issues when the action button is clicked, I added a navigator to send the user to a particular page but it only takes them to the homepage inside my `onActionReceivedMethod`. I have my code as below:

```
Future<void> onActionReceivedMethod(
    ReceivedAction receivedAction) async {

  Navigator.of(contxt).push(
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => UploadImageDemo()));

}


Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {

  bool isAllowed = await AwesomeNotifications().isNotificationAllowed();
    if (!isAllowed) return;
    await AwesomeNotifications().createNotification(
        content: NotificationContent(
            id: -1,
            channelKey: 'alerts',
            title: message.notification.title,
            body: message.notification.body,
            bigPicture: 'https://storage.googleapis.com/cms-storage-bucket/d406c736e7c4c57f5f61.png',
            largeIcon: 'https://storage.googleapis.com/cms-storage-bucket/d406c736e7c4c57f5f61.png',
           notificationLayout: NotificationLayout.BigPicture,
            payload: {'notificationId': '1234567890'}),
        actionButtons: [
          NotificationActionButton(key: 'REDIRECT', label: 'Use',color: Colors.white),

       
          NotificationActionButton(
              key: 'DISMISS',
              label: 'Dismiss',
              actionType: ActionType.DismissAction,
              isDangerousOption: true,color: Colors.red)
        ]
    );
}


void main() async {
   WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
   await Firebase.initializeApp();

  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);
    NotificationController.startListeningNotificationEvents();

}

class NotificationController {


 static Future<void> startListeningNotificationEvents() async {
    AwesomeNotifications()
        .setListeners(onActionReceivedMethod: onActionReceivedMethod);
  }

}
```

As seen above I added all the necessary functions and all seem to be work except the navigation at  `onActionReceivedMethod` I will be glad if anyone can help out with this as I tried troubleshooting but couldn't see any error in my terminal except below:

```
W/FirebaseMessaging(18850): Notification Channel requested (fcm_default_channel) has not been created by the app. Manifest configuration, or default, value will be used.
W/FirebaseMessaging(18850): Missing Default Notification Channel metadata in AndroidManifest. Default value will be used.
I/System.out(18850): (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
I/System.out(18850): (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
```